# My Custom Post type posts are showing as page not found

Tags: wordpress

I created a custom post type called Recipes but my posts are showing as "page not found".

This is a link to one of the posts I created - http://pt1-dev.info/recipes/festive-napa-cabbage/ But it shows as page not found.

Also my theme doesn't show on my page.  (It's just a test site to make this work so only the navigation and footer box should show)

Here is my code -

```
    // Register Custom Post Types
add_action('init', 'register_custom_posts_init');
function register_custom_posts_init() {
    // Register Recipes
    $recipes_labels = array(
        'name'               => 'Recipes',
        'singular_name'      => 'Recipe',
        'menu_name'          => 'Recipes'
    );
    $recipes_args = array(
        'labels'             => $recipes_labels,
        'public'             => true,
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'  => true,
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'revisions' )

    );
    register_post_type('recipes', $recipes_args);
}

add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type', 0 );


function tr_create_my_taxonomy() {

    register_taxonomy(
        'recipes-category',
        'recipes',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Recipe Category' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'recipes-category' ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'tr_create_my_taxonomy' );
```

This is what I have the file recipes.php I created -

```
<?php
        // Posts are found
        if ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $posts->have_posts() ) :
                $posts->the_post();
                global $post;
                ?>

 $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'recipes',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => '10'
  );
  $recipes_loop = new WP_Query( $args );
  if ( $recipes_loop->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $recipes_loop->have_posts() ) : $recipes_loop->the_post();
      // Set variables
      $title = get_the_title();
      $description = get_the_content();
      $recipeby = get_field('recipe_by');
      $category = get_field('category');
      $recipe_description = get_field('recipe_description');
 $image = get_field('recipe_image');
  if (!empty($image)) {
    $url = get_field('hlink');
?>    
      <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php 
          echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php 
          echo $image['alt']; ?>" /></a>
<?php
}

$yields = get_field('yields');
$prep = get_field('prep_time');
$cook = get_field('cook_time');
$total = get_field('total_time');

$ingredients = get_field('ingredients');
$instructions = get_field('instructions');


      endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
  endif;
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Updated single-recipe.php file -

```
<?php

/*
* Template Name: Recipes
*/

get_header(); ?>

        <div id="primary" class="clearfix">

            <div id="content" role="main" class="clearfix">

<header class="blog-entry-header clearfix">

            <?php if ( is_sticky() ) : ?>

                <hgroup>

                    <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'azurebasic' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

                    <h3 class="entry-format"><?php _e( 'Featured', 'azurebasic' ); ?></h3>

                </hgroup>

            <?php else : ?>
<h1 class="blog-entry-title clearfix"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'azurebasic' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>


 <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


        </header><!-- .entry-header -->


 $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'recipes',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => '10'
  );
  $recipes_loop = new WP_Query( $args );
  if ( $recipes_loop->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $recipes_loop->have_posts() ) : $recipes_loop->the_post();
      // Set variables



      $title = get_the_title();
      $description = get_the_content();
      $recipeby = get_field('recipe_by');
      $category = get_field('category');
      $recipe_description = get_field('recipe_description');
 $image = get_field('recipe_image');
  if (!empty($image)) {
    $url = get_field('hlink');
?>    
      <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php 
          echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php 
          echo $image['alt']; ?>" /></a>
<?php
}

$yields = get_field('yields');
$prep = get_field('prep_time');
$cook = get_field('cook_time');
$total = get_field('total_time');

$ingredients = get_field('ingredients');
$instructions = get_field('instructions');


      endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
  endif;




                    <nav id="nav-single" class="clearfix">

                        <h4 class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Post Navigation', 'azurebasic' ); ?></h4>

                        <span class="nav-next"><?php next_post_link( '%link', __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Next', 'azurebasic' ) ); ?></span>

                        <span class="nav-previous"><?php previous_post_link( '%link', __( 'Previous <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'azurebasic' ) ); ?></span>

                    </nav><!-- #nav-single -->



                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>



            </div><!-- #content -->

        </div><!-- #primary -->


<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<div class="clear"></div><!-- .clear the floats -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Did you try to save the permalink settings after creating/registering the custom post types?

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!  That fixed it!! This was driving me crazy!!  Thank you so much zipkundan!!

Comment: So that fixed that problem.  But now I have 2 more problems -  I created a category called "Salad" and I chose that category in my post but "salads" doesn't show up in the url.  Shouldn't it show so I can show specific categories on a page?  The other issue is that the field I created in Advanced Custom Fields is not displaying on the front end.  I filled in the fields but they don't show on the page.

Comment: For the category to display in URL you will need to set the permalink structure accordingly. Which option have you set for permalink structure? And for the custom field to show up on front end you will need to edit the template code to add that field, so that it shows there.

Comment: Thank you for your help zipkundan!  I am using "post name" for the permalink structure.  If that's not correct what should I use?  This is my first attempt at creating a template so how should I edit the template code to show on the front end?  I added the fields to it but they aren't showing up. is there something I am missing in my code?  I added the code I'm using above.

Comment: I see that you have stored the custom field's values in respective variables. You will need to 'echo' those variable to be displayed in the content. e.g. 'echo($yields)'. Wrap the echo statement with appropriate html.

Comment: I feel like the recipe.php file I created is not being found for the custom posts types I created.  Is that possible?  Is there something special I need to add to the file to be found if that is the case?

Comment: Your custom post should automatically pickup the default template 'single.php'. Specifically for your custom post type, you can copy the same file and rename it as 'single-recipes.php'. Save the permalink structure once again after creating the file. Confirm that that this new template file is picked up by your custom post types and then you can edit the code in this file for displaying the custom fields data.

Comment: I so appreciate your help zipkundan!  I changed the code in my file and renamed it to single-recipes.php but something is not right because the page is broke now.  I added the new code to my original question above, would you mind taking a look and letting me know if you can see what is wrong with it?  http://pt1-dev.info/my-recipes/ is the page.  This is my first attempt at custom post types so I'm not sure what I'm doing and am failing miserably!  Thank you again!!

Comment: For the archive page you (the main page with all recipes), you need to use `archive-recipes.php`, `single-recipes.php` is for the single recipe page - this resource is super helpful in figuring out how to name your templates https://wphierarchy.com/

Comment: Oh so I need to create 2 php files?  An archive file and a single file?  I'm so sorry to sound so stupid but do I have to connect them somehow or will they by default?

Comment: You do not need to connect them. Those are separate template files. Just like your created *single-recipes.php* from *single.php*, you can create *archive-recipes.php* from *archive.php*.

Comment: Thank you!!  I have that all working now, but my biggest problem is I can't get my Advanced Custom Fields to show up in the front end.  I added a line of text "This is my recipe" to one of the recipes I added in the default wysiwyg editor and that shows but not any of my acf fields.  Do you see anything I did wrong in my coding by chance?

Comment: I finally got it all to work!!  I watched a youtube tutorial and it's working now.  @Zipkundan - I had to 'echo' the variables like you said and that worked.  I just didn't know how to do it.  Once I watched the tutorial I totally understood it.  Thank you for your help!!